# How to avoid using the deprecated Date constructor while dealing with Oracle date data type?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, datetime, oracle10g

I'm working with Spring 3.0.2 using Hibernate 3.2.1 and Oracle 10g as a back end. In an Oracle database table, there is a field whose data type is `Date`. This `Date` type field is mapped with `java.util.Date` in Hibernate (POJO) something like the following.

```
private Date discountStartDate;
```

While inserting or updating data into the Oracle table, I'm supplying a `java.lang.String` type date something like this `08/15/2012 15:08:13`. There is no problem at all. Everything works well but since Oracle date data type (as far my knowledge) is always mapped with `java.util.Date` with Hibernate entity, I can't use other Java APIs like Calendar and I have to use the **deprecated** constructor of the `Date` class to deal with Hibernate as follows.

```
Discount obj=new Discount();
date=new Date(request.getParameter("txtDiscountStartDate"));
obj.setDiscountStartDate(date);
```

Such deprecated functionality should be avoided. Is there a way to get around this deprecated <s>Date</s>("StringDate") constructor in Hibernate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's wrong.

You should be parsing that `String` into a `Date` using `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

[Here](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/) is an example.

Here's another, since this seems difficult for you:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd");
formatter.setLenient(false);
String discountDateAsString = request.getParameter("txtDiscountStartDate");
Date discountDate = formatter.parse(discountDateAsString);
```

Comment: But parsing with `SimpleDateFormat` or `DateFormat` requires this statement `date=new Date(request.getParameter("txtDiscountEndDate"));` before the actual parsing is made like `date=new Date(request.getParameter("txtDiscountEndDate"));`
                        `DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("someFormat");`
                        `df.format(date);`

Comment: It was done. Which date format is considered by default, if no format is specified with this constructor `new SimpleDateFormat();`? I tried with no format but it didn't work in my case and had to specify explicitly the date format with another overloaded constructor. Thank you.

Comment: There is no default.  You've got to spell out what you want.  No mind reading allowed.